# Bootstrap CSS Background-color not working

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using V3.3.6 of Bootstrap and I wanted the background-color of my Ņavbar to be a dark red. In addition to the standard Bootstrap CSS, I have my own css as shown below:

```
    .navbar-inverse {
      background-color: #9E1B34;
    }

    .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a,
    .navbar-inverse .navbar-brand {
      color: white;
    }
    .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a,
    .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
    .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus,
    .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
    .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a:focus,
    .navbar-inverse .navbar-brand:hover,
    .navbar-inverse .navbar-brand:focus  {
      color: #9E1B34;
      background-color: white;
    }
```

The website is http://www.alkd.org.au

When hovering over each navbar item I get my correct styling of Red text and White background. But the background-color of the standard navbar is black, not dark red even though I have overridden the .navbar-inverse background-color. The browser developer tools shows that my css is the 'winning'  one yet seems to be ignored. I cannot find anything in the developer tool that shows me where the black is coming from. I do have a javascript that adds the active class to the active page which sets the text color to red (which is working), but the background color should be white. Once again the developer tools shows that the active page background-color is white but it is being displayed as black.
Where is that black coming from? and whats the best way to get rid of it please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The black color is actually coming from a gradient on the `.navbar-inverse` class.
Adding `backgound-image` none will override this.

```
.navbar-inverse {
    background-color: #9E1B34;
    background-image: none;
}
```

This also allows you to remove the `!important` which makes the code more maintainable.

Comment: When I first coded the web page, the colors were fine. They must have recently added the gradient to bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

The most simple solution:

```
.navbar-inverse {
    background: #9E1B34;
}
```

Your `background-color` was covered by `background-image` property that created black gradient.

Now, combined property `background` allows you to set new background color, while setting `background-image` to `none`.